# Physically remove a drive where another windows is installed

Tags: windows, boot

I recently bought a second ssd, where I installed windows as I did with my old.
Currently, Windows made a "dual boot".

Now I want to take this old ssd and put it in another PC I'm building. The problem is, windows won't boot if I unplug the another ssd (no problem with the others disks, my guess is it's related to the boot manager failing to find everything its looking for).

I removed the "old ssd" windows entry from the boot manager without problem and the window for the dual boot won't even show now, but it's still not booting if it doesn't have access to the yet unused other OS.

`boosect` hasn't worked, unfortunately.

I've encoutered this multiples times in my life actually, and the only solution I found to date is to unplug the other windows drive before installing.. But I'd like to avoid resetting my windows installation again.

EDIT : `bootsect` didn't work even with two partitions on the boot drive.

Comment: How many partitions are on the new SSD? For a UEFI bootable system there have to be at least 2 or 3 partitions. The first two should be very small (100-500MB).

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that windows didn't create the usual  "reserved for system" partition... Now I know bootsect will say everything is ok, even if it couldn't actually do its job

Comment: Nevermind, having two partitions didn't help. The supposedly created bootmgr is not doing anything.

Comment: If you have tow partitions (in the correct order, correct type and correct file-system) you can use your Windows install disk  to repair the boot process.